# Is there a way to share passwords among multiple users without others knowing the password itself

Tags: passwords, mysql, password-management, password-protection

We have a team of developers who need to access the `mysql` production server, but they should not have access to the password. I am looking for a mechanism where they can copy the password into the clipboard and paste the password during mysql access. How to achieve this?

Comment: Could you not create separate accounts for them with access to what they need? That way you can delete their account/remove permissions when their need for access is over?

Comment: Yeah, this is what multiple accounts are for in the first place...besides, if you're letting them in you're letting them in, it doesn't matter if they KNOW the password if they can still get in...I don't need the keys to your house if you leave the door unlocked...

Comment: Once it's in their clipboard, they could paste it anywhere they wanted, so your proposed method ultimately wouldn't prevent them from seeing the password.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than trying to find an unlikely method for sharing a password without sharing the password, create separate user accounts for each person who needs access, giving each his/her own password. Instructions to create and administer MySQL users are available [on the MySQL website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-account-management.html).

In this way, each person who needs access would have their own account, and this account could be deleted, or privileges removed, when access is no longer needed. This has the added benefit of allowing [account-based auditing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/account-activity-auditing.html), so that if something gets screwed up, you can trace it back to the user who made the change.